# Inequality Question find the value of x+y

Tags: inequality

If $x^{\frac{y}{2}}=64$ and it is given that $y>3$, $x<64$ and $x>y$, what is the value of $x+y$. I reduced the given equation to $x^y=4096$ and formed an a new inequality $x+y>6$ but could not get anywhere with that. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking logarithm base $2$  $$\frac y2\log_2x=6\iff\log_2 x=\frac{12}y<4\iff x<2^4=16$$

So, we have $3<y<x<16$

If $x$ is power of $2,x$ can only be $2^3$(why?)

In that case $\displaystyle(2^3)^{\frac y2}=64=2^6\implies y=4$

Comment: why is $\frac{12}{y}<4$?

Comment: As $y>3,\dfrac1y<\dfrac13$

Comment: how do you go from $lnx<4$ to $x<2^4$?

Comment: @user140161, $$\log_2x<4=4\log_22=\log_2(2^4)\implies\log_2x<\log_2(16)$$

Answer (score 0):

You have that $x^y=4096=2^{12}$ now since $y>3$ you can have that $y=4,6,12$ and since $x>y$ we have that $y=6,12$ do not fit and $y=4$ fits all criteria so you have that $x=2^3=8$ so $x+y=12$